# Open a Facebook link on Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

If the native Facebook app is installed on the WindowsPhone. How do I open a Facebook link into the native Facebook app from my app.

example link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/notifications
```

If native app is not installed, i wish to launch browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use this uri to launch your facebook application:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:post?text=foo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch Facebook app using:

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:XX")); // where XX is facebook id

if(!success) { // in case of fail
    WebBrowserTask wbtask = new WebBrowserTask();
    wbtask.Url = "yourUrlHere";
    wbtask.Show();
}
```

You can read more about LauncheUriAsync [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh701480.aspx)